# Как перед сохранением в sqlite выполнить проверку?

Tags: php, sqlite

Делаю проверку по **wareUrl**, если wareUrl уже есть в базе то пропускаю.

Мой код:

```
public function exists($item, $type)
{
    return (bool)$this->sqlite->querySingle('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `items` WHERE `type` = ' . $type . ' AND `wareUrl` = \'' . SQLite3::escapeString($item->wareUrl) . '\'');
}
```

Все работает, но если один wareUrl задан как http://site.ru, а второй http://site.ru/ - сахраняет оба варианта.

Как перед сохранение wareUrl получить адрес без слеша на конце?

Проверка просто по домену не подойдет т.к. адреса могут иметь вид http://site.ru/1.html и http://site.ru/2.html, в этом случае сохранить нужно оба варианта.

Comment: дак сделайте `trim`

Comment: Как можно сделать trim?

Comment: `trim($item->wareUrl, '/')` так наверное?

Comment: На каком шагу это делать, пока не понятно.

Comment: сами ведь сказали, перед сохранением

Comment: Понял, спасибо!